# Custom .css file for custom block

Tags: css, frontend, block

I have a custom block and I've modified the looks of it by writing the style attributes directly into the `.phtml` file between  tags.

I want to have a separate file for this, so my block would use my custom .css file. If I create it then where should I put it and what else should I do so my block would know to look for that file?

**EDIT**

It is for Magento!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about plain old HTML style. So your solution goes like this.

1) Create a Folder named CSS in the same folder where you have your HTML file stored.
2) In CSS folder create a .css file.
3) In your HTML file in the header portion add the link to the CSS.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/temp.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

In case of Magento

```html
<action method="addItem"><type>external_css</type><name>path/temp.css</name><params/></action>
```

Same can be used for external JS file

Comment: Whoop, it was actually meant for Magento.

Comment: did the above snippet for Magento help? @anthony

Comment: Where should I add this <action method="addItem> snippet? And how would it know to apply this css to my custom block? And not on anything else.

Comment: Add it to the layout.xml under <reference name="head">

Comment: I can't find the file called layout.xml. Where is this file's location?

Comment: Try this path if you can relate to it..app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout